# Why does the following program stops working after taking the inputs in the array?

Tags: c, arrays, max, scanf, min

I wrote the following program for finding the largest and the smallest element of an array. The program takes the input of the array but then stops working. What is the reason behind that ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i,l,s,t;
    printf("Enter number of inputs.\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n];
    printf("Enter inputs.\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    l=a[0];
    s=a[0];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>l)
        {
            l=a[i];
        }
        if(a[i]<s)
        {
            s=a[i];
        }
    }
    printf("max = %d , min = %d\n",l,s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The program will stop working after doing everything in the program. What is the problem? You have SEGV or somthing?

Comment: @MikeCAT It does not do everything it is supposed to. It only allows to enter the elements of the array and after that a error message appears "Program.exe has stooped working.".

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling and running the code you pasted? You're missing a `"` character on line 10 of what you pasted.

Comment: One of the hallmarks of a good "it's not doing what I expect" question is to indicate what you expect and what you got. If you include what you expect and what you got, then you'll get better help much faster.

Comment: *"... but then stops working"* is not a good problem statement. You should provide details of how it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing one `"` symbol here:

```
printf("Enter of inputs.\n);
```

After that, it works well for me (on Linux), with only a certainly harmless warning:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra t.c
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:6:17: warning: unused variable ‘t’ [-Wunused-variable]
     int n,i,l,s,t;

$ ./a.out
Enter number of inputs.
1
Enter of inputs.
1
max = 1 , min = 1
$ ./a.out
Enter number of inputs.
10
Enter of inputs.
20
21
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
2023
max = 2023 , min = 20
```

Possibly you had that typo and *thought* you had recompiled it, but then went on to run an old executable (because it was not able to recompile)?

Answer (score 0):

In cpp for dynamic array should use this syntax.

```
int *a = new int[n] ;
```

if you like to use cpp and you want to have dynamic list you can use vector

```
std::vector<int> a;
```

Comment: Its written in C rather than cpp.

Comment: C++ does not support dynamic arrays. And C is a different languaeg anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First things first your code has a missing closing " in the printf statement below. Your code is working fine.

```
printf("Enter of inputs.\n");
```

There can be one more possibility, you might be using some IDE that closes the result window at the end of the program you can try placing `getchar()` before `return` to hold the screen.

Comment: That is a mistake I did while copying it here.

Comment: @AASingh check the answer now

Answer (score 0):

Well, You didnt provide output(printf statement) of largest and smallest number after finding them. Program should be like this :-

```
int main()
{
int n,i,l,s,t;
printf("Enter number of inputs.\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
int a[n];
printf("Enter of inputs.\n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}
l=a[0];
s=a[0];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(a[i]>l)
    {
        l=a[i];
    }
    if(a[i]<s)
    {
        s=a[i];
    }
}
printf("Largest no : %d and smallest no : %d",l,s);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you be more explicit on how is your suggestion improving on OP's code?